# why "from childhood " without any articles or possessive pronouns

Tags: articles

As titled, I've seen the phrases  like ''from childhood", "since childhood" leave out articles or possessive  pronouns.

Are there any reasons?

Comment: "Childhood" is an abstract non-count noun here used indefinitely, so no article is required. But that doesn't mean that it can't take genitive pronouns as a definite determiner, e.g. "... from/since my childhood".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this case, *childhood* represents a state of being and is not something that can be quantified. In a sense, it's kind of like a mass noun and mass nouns, as you probably know, don't take indefinite articles. For example: *He is 27 years of age*. You wouldn't say *27 years of **the** age* or *27 years of **an** age*, would you? We're not talking about a particular age, but rather about age as a general concept of how much time in years a person has lived so far.

Comment: Can I say from my childhood,instead?

Comment: Sure you can. For example: **I can't remember anything from my childhood.**